# How to play specific keyframes with css animation

Tags: css

I want to play keyframes 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 with css animation:

This doesn't work:

```
@keyframes play-specific {
  0% {
    background-position:    0px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position:    -50px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position:    -100px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position:    -50px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -0px;
  }
}
```

with animation:

```
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");

    animation: play-specific 1s steps(4) infinite;
}
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12960/

Comment: you should set steps to (1)  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVEPZY (so it jumps in 1 time to each keyframes you set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

steps() will break animation from a keyframes to another. it can be used to avoid to set each keyframes.

When keyframes are set , 1 will mean jump from a keyframe to another without transition.

```css
.hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
            animation: play-specific 1s steps(1) infinite;
}
.ho {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
            animation: play 1s steps(10) infinite;
}
@keyframes play-specific {/* steps() will be applied in between each keyframes, 1 is to jump from a keyframe to another without transition */
  0% {
    background-position:    0px;
  }
  25% {
    background-position:    -50px;
  }
  50% {
    background-position:    -100px;
  }
  75% {
    background-position:    -50px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -0px;
  }
}

@keyframes play {/* steps here need to be adapted in order to break the linearity of animation */
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="hi"></div>
<div class="ho"></div>
```

see on W3C

> [For a keyframed animation, the 'animation-timing-function' applies between keyframes, not over the entire animation. For example, in the case of an ease-in-out timing function, an animation will ease in at the start of the keyframe and ease out at the end of the keyframe. A 'animation-timing-function' defined within a keyframe block applies to that keyframe, otherwise the timing function specified for the animation is used.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-animations-20120403/#animation-timing-function)